# React Context API: value is undefined in consumer component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context, react-state-management

I have been trying to add state-management to my react app using React ContextAPI, but I am running into an issue. I am using class components, the idea is here to get data from a component using Axios and pass data to a dashboard to summarize the data.

Component A -- > Provider component

Component B --> Consumer component

Component C -- > Dashboard -- > Consuming ComponentB

When I browse the dashboard, the state value always comes undefined.
Any suggestions on how I can resolve this? Appreciate your help.

package.json
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",

> **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import ComponentA from "./components/a"
import "rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.min.css";
import SomeContext from "./context/context.js";

class App extends Component {
state = {};
render() {
 return (
   <React.Fragment>
     <Sidebar />
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
         <Route path="/a" component={ComponentA} />
       </Switch>
   </React.Fragment>
 );
}
}

export default App;
```

> **SomeContext.js**

```
    import React from "react";

    const SomeContext = React.createContext();
    SomeContext.displayName = "SomeContext";


    export default SomeContext;
```

> **Component A -->  Provider Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Card, CardHeader, Table, Container, Row } from "reactstrap";
import SomeContext from "./context/context.js";
class ComponentA extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: posts } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api");
    this.setState({ posts });
    console.log(posts);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-content" ref="main-content">

        <Container fluid>
          <SomeContext.Provider value={{ state:this.state }}>
            <ComponentB/>   
            **.....Some component code **

            </SomeContext.Provider>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentA;
```

> **Component B -- Consuming data from ComponentA**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SomeContext from "./context/context.js";

class ComponentB extends Component {
static contextType = SomeContext;

  render() {
    return (
      <SomeContext.Consumer>
        {(dashboard) => (
          <div>Data: {dashboard} {console.log(dashboard)} </div>

        )}
    </SomeContext.Consumer>
        );
      }
    }

export default ComponentB;
```

> **Dashboard**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ComponentB from "./components/b";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-content">
        <ComponentB />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: it doesn't look like your Dashboard component is a child of your Provider

Comment: You must place your `Consumer` under (inside) your `Provider` in order to get it work. `ComponentB`, which is the `Consumer`, is not under the `Provider`, which is `ComponentA`.

Comment: @CamSong thanks for your reply, I added ComponentB inside the provider ComponentA. But I still get undefined

Comment: The `ComponentB` which is under `DashBoard` is meaningless, isn't it? You still get what undefined?

Comment: @CamSong why is it meaningless? I want to display ComponentB on the dashboard. When I browse /dashboard I am expecting the dashboard component to load with ComponentB in it with the data passed by ComponentA. Yes I still get undefined,

Comment: As `DashBoard` is not the `Provider` but `ComponentA`, so you can't use the `Consumer`, which is `ComponentB`, under `DashBoard` like that!

Comment: If you want to get it work on `DashBoard`, try moving the data fetching and context Provider from `ComponentA` to `DashBoard` -> So basically you will no longer need the `ComponentA` anymore!

Comment: @camsong thanks, I need the data in component A as well, if I had to directly pass from parent to child component, props would have done it, Component A is a table which displays text data and dashboard displays graphs for that data. the idea is  /dashboard will display data graphs from multiple components.

Comment: ComponentB is a reusable component

Comment: I got your intention here. Let switch to this approach: `DashBoard` will be the parent layer (=container), which is responsible for 2 things: data fetching and context provider. `ComponentA` is now under `DashBoard`, which still remains the same role: displaying the text data. Besides, `ComponentA` also becomes a `Consumer` to retrieve data from `Provider`, which is `DashBoard`. Lastly, `ComponentB` is nested under `DashBoard` as well as `ComponentA`, which is responsible for displaying the graphs.

Comment: **Smart component**: `Dashboard`. **Dumb components**: `ComponentA`, `ComponentB`

Comment: If I make the Dashboard component as a parent/Global component, it will have to data fetch for other components C, D, E as well. Will it impact the performance or load time of the application?

Comment: Yes, It will. Once the `DashBoard` are triggered a re-render, all of nested components that are under `DashBoard` will be triggered a re-render too. To avoid that, the best approach is to switch to Redux, and abandon the lifting-state-up behavior like this. In case you are vague about what lifting-state-up means, please refer to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: However, performance issue is not something to care about in this case. Have a try on the approach which I recommended above, it will make your life easier!

Comment: @CamSong thanks, will try it out, I was trying to avoid redux, it is another learning curve.

Comment: Not that hard, go easy on it! One of the many advantages in using Redux for state management, is that it allows you to avoid calling the async action a.k.a side-effect like data fetching inside your component, by using some middleware like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`. As the component grows, you could still keep your component stay clean.

Comment: Ok, let me try it out, want to set the application the right way so it can grow in the future. thanks again @CamSong.

Comment: @CKS hey there, in order to help future readers get this post quickly, I have submitted a brief answer. Upvote and mark accept if you find it useful! Please feel free to keep in touch if there is anything that might bug you in future!

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to get the `Consumer` work, you must place it under the `Provider`. As `DashBoard` is not the `Provider` but `ComponentA`, so you can't use the `Consumer`, which is `ComponentB`, under `DashBoard` like that.
2. For better components organization, I recommend this approach:

`DashBoard` will be the parent layer (container), which is responsible for 2 things: data fetching and context provider.

`ComponentA` is now under `DashBoard`, which still remains the same role: displaying the text data. Besides, it also becomes a `Consumer` to retrieve data from `Provider`, which is `DashBoard` now.

Lastly, `ComponentB` is nested under `DashBoard` as well as `ComponentA`, which is responsible for displaying the graphs.

Please also consider using a meaningful name to name after your components. For example:

`ComponentA` -> `DisplayTextData`

`ComponentB` -> `DisplayGraph`

So in the end, you will have something like this:

**Smart component**: `Dashboard`

**Dumb components**: `DisplayTextData`, `DisplayGraph`

In case you have no idea what smart/dumb component means, please refer to this article written by Dan Abramov: [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). Keep in mind that **it's always a good practice that you should decrease the number of smart components, and increase the number of dumb components.**

3. In order to keep your components stay clean, please consider switching to Redux. One of the many advantages in using Redux for state management, is that it allows you to avoid calling async actions a.k.a side-effect like data fetching inside your components.